# Why does this query match the wrong database name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why does 'TestDatabase2' also match 'TestDatabase'? Similarly, 'D2' also matches 'D'.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP 1
                    sdb.name AS DbName,
                    bus.backup_start_date AS LastBackUpTime,
                    bus.type AS Type
                FROM
                    sys.sysdatabases sdb 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    msdb.dbo.backupset bus
                ON
                    bus.database_name = sdb.NAME
                    AND
                    bus.type = @backupType
                WHERE
                    sdb.name = @dbname
                ORDER BY
                    LastBackUpTime DESC',N'@dbName nvarchar(12),@backupType nvarchar(1)',@dbName=N'TestDatabase',@backupType=N'D'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parameter for the Database name is an `NVARCHAR(12)`.

Guess how many characters `TestDatabase` is ;)

```
SELECT CAST('TestDatabase' as NVARCHAR(12)), CAST('TestDatabase12314' as NVARCHAR(12))
```

You should make it an `NVARCHAR(128)` or a `SYSNAME`, which is the length of the `msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name` and `sys.databases.name` columns.

Comment: You could also just use `sysname` as the data type.

Comment: Aha... the length was generated by ADO.net.